# How can I negate hidden directive in html template?

Tags: html, components, ionic2, hidden

In a Ionic2 component I use the [hidden] directive in the HTML template. The @Component definition is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'login-button',
  template:
    `<button ion-button round (click)="openLogin()" [hidden]="loggedIn">
        Login
        <ion-icon name="arrow-up"></ion-icon>
      </button>

      <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle [hidden]="!loggedIn">
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    `
})
```

I declare a component variable:

```
export class LoginButton {

  loggedIn: boolean = false;
```

The `[hidden]="loggedIn"` is working. The `[hidden]="!loggedIn"` shows the button no matter of the value of loggedIn variable.

How do I write that?

Comment: I just want to add that when performances are needed, this seems to be good practice to use `*ngIf` instead of `hidden` : ["the fastest code is code that is not run and the fastest DOM is DOM that doesn’t exist"](https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/05/04/angular-2-best-practices-change-detector-performance/) (Official Angular2 reference [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#visibility-and-ngif-are-not-the-same)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf` declaration. Example :

```
    <div *ngIf = "loggedIn">
          <button ion-button round (click)="openLogin()">
            Login
            <ion-icon name="arrow-up"></ion-icon>
          </button>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf = "!loggedIn">
          <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
          </button>
    </div>

--------------> Edit

          <button ion-button round (click)="openLogin()" [hidden]="hideLogin1()">
            Login
            <ion-icon name="arrow-up"></ion-icon>
          </button>



          <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle [hidden]="hideLogin2()">
            <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
          </button>
-----------------------------
export class LoginButton {
        hideLogin1(){
            return true;
        }   

        hideLogin2(){
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: This is working. Thx. But I looked for the solution with hidden directive. I know it works ... Just not in this case.

Comment: try this method with functionaly: hideDiv1(){
        return true;
    }   

    hideDiv2(){
        return false;
    }

Comment: `<button ion-button round (click)="openLogin()" [hidden]="hideButton1">

Comment: Ok. That is a way.

Comment: Burhan Gül, with this answer, how will you change the visibility state when `openLogin()` finishes?

Comment: sorry, this code is missing. if you add  the hideLogin2() function to in openLogin() , its operate when clicked button and returns true or false. Or Login button is visible  in this way

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand :s. If I use `hideLogin2()` inside `openLogin()`, it will return `false` only inside the `openLogin()` scope so how will it change the visible state?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you are experimenting the first mistake explained [here](http://angularjs.blogspot.fr/2016/04/5-rookie-mistakes-to-avoid-with-angular.html)?

<s>Moreover, in Ionic2 you can also use `showWhen` and `hideWhen` (documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/show-hide-when/ShowWhen/)), could it fit your need?</s>

Comment: The first is the proper explanation for my problem. The second seems only to work for platforms and screen orientations.

Comment: So, do you think that the Ionic CSS (or yours) carries low specificity and is o overrided accidentally by the `display : none;` property settled by the `hidden` property? For me, it would make sense.

Comment: Sorry for the second, I misunderstood the signature of `showWhen` and `hideWhen`. I thought that `platforms` were simply boolean provided by the build step.